# Git: set master identical to develop

Tags: git

I cannot get my master and develop branches to be identical. I want my master branch to look exactly like my develop branch as it currently exists, but somehow despite file name changes and deletion of directories in develop, those filenames and directories still exist in master no matter a merge, which just tells me that everything is up to date so I'm stuck as to how to get master to change without doing it manually, which is sure to be error prone.

Comment: What’s the output of `git status` on `develop`?

Comment: Have you merged each branch into the other? Have you committed all changes before doing so?

Comment: `git checkout master && git merge develop`?

Comment: what's the output of `git log --graph --branches --oneline --format=format:'%h%d'` ?

Comment: Yes. All branches were fully committed, all branches were up to date with origin etc. I finally got what I wanted when I did the following: I cloned from origin into a new repo. It immediately told me I was behind origin by 8 commits, despite having just cloned from it. So I pushed back to origin, returned to my other (original) repo, pulled from origin and it updated...something. Then I checked out master, merged develop, and voila. I have no idea what happened since I was getting feedback from Git in every direction that nothing was out of sync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do here is a [`git reset`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html) so that your master branch points at the same location as the develop branch. Note that you will loose everything on master that is not in develop.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <sha1 of develop>
```

After that, master and develop both point to the same commit.